# Http request on iOS app starting

Tags: ios, swift

I want to send http request on every myapp-starting.
How to do this? I try:

```
class MainViewController: UITableViewController {
func my_request(){

        let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.stackoverflow.com")
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
        let connection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate:nil, startImmediately: true)
        println(connection)

        }

        let lol = my_request()
}
```

But I have an error: **Missing argument for parameter #1 in call**

How to fix that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my_request() returns nothing, if you just want to call the function, use only

```
my_request()
```

I would suggest to put this in the ViewDidLoad function (on your Main ViewController of your App)